# NotSerializableException and the Clipboard

Tags: clipboard, serializable

I know I need to implement `Serializable` in the classes which neet to be set to the Clipboard. But for the Objects with objects as attributes in them, do I need to implement `Serializable` on all the object attributes. And does it follow that I need to implement `Serializable` in the Objects within object attributes?

For example

```
TestObject implements Serializable
{
   private Object o = new Object();
}

Object o implements Serializable
{
   private AnotherObject ao = new AnotherObject()
}
```

does "AnotherObject" have to be serializable too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes every object you want to serialize should implement Serializable (even though it is part of another serializable object)